# Newbie Contract Creation Question

Tags: transactions, erc-20, contract-deployment

Complete newbie here so thanks in advance for tolerating the ignorance that follows.

I'm starting from the very beginning learning how to create and deploy my own tokens. And I'm going through and looking at various tokens and peeking into their ledger history on Etherscan.

On a number of tokens that I've looked at have this transaction as the very first transaction in the ledger:

[image]

My 2 question are  -

1. Is this first ledger transaction the signed transaction that "creates" the token contract?
2. How'd this particular token get Vb as the "From" Wallet???

Hope this makes sense. Thanks for any help you can offer to a newbie trying to understand all this stuff!

Comment: Sorry! Question 1 should have been stated - "1. Is this first ledger transaction the signed transaction that "creates" the token CONTRACT?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction in your example is masked, so I can't really tell, but it does not look like a Contract Creation transaction.

1. The first transaction that you see on a contract page is the Contract creation transaction. The `to` address is the contract's address. The `from` address is the address of whoever deployed it. Here is an [example](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2f1c5c2b44f771e942a8506148e256f94f1a464babc938ae0690c6e34cd79190) (the USDT contract deployment transaction).
2. Etherscan choose to show a word or letters instead of the contract address for some famous addresses. In this case, Vb is no other than Vitalik Buterin. Etherscan simply chose to show it that way because he publicly disclosed his address and he is famous. Of course, his real address is 0xAb5801a7D398351b8bE11C439e05C5B3259aeC9B and not Vb (you can see the address by clicking on Vb).

Edit based on comments: The Tokens Transferred line (from X to Y) on Etherscan is generated based on the Events broadcasted by the contract. ERC-20 tokens will broadcast an event on transfers between X to Y and then Etherscan generates that line. However, it is easy to create a contract that broadcast a fake event to fool people into thinking that X chose to transfer tokens to Y even if X was not involved at all in the transaction. I suspect that Vb had nothing to do with that token transfer.

Comment: You can accept the answer if you are satisfied by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: Thank you! I masked the hash and wallets so as to not give anything away. So cool about Vitalik!

So when I click onto the transaction hash for the above transaction, I see this:

[link] (https://imgur.com/GQeBIPi)

What role would Vitalik have had in this contract deployment?

Comment: Vb did not deploy the contract, the masked address did. The line where you see that Vb transferred tokens to an address does not require the Vb address to sign a transaction and could be fake (and probably is fake). Anyone could create a contract that displays a token transfer from any address to any other address to deceive people.

Comment: @Newbie I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, I believe this token was a known scam I discovered from Token Sniffer, but I hadn't seen that type of line before.
Now that I've been looking, I've seen seen similar "emits" in various contracts I've been exploring. For example, one contract had the same line but instead of VB's address, it was 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

Is the only purpose of such an "emit event" to deceive? And what would be the purpose of using 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000?

Sorry for all the questions. I've taken up too much of your time already. Very grateful for all the help!

Comment: No worry! Just ask a new question since this is a bit of a different topic.